# If a Ball can be any of $n$ colors, then the number of configurations (with repetition of colors) of $k$ balls is $(n+k-1)C(k)$ why?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

For example, if a ball can be any of 3 colors, then the number of configurations (with repetition of colors) of 2 balls is $(3+2-1)C_{2} = 4C_{2} = 6$ Why?

Comment: Why isn't it $3\cdot3=9$?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘configuration’? If I understand the problem correctly then each of the k balls will have n choices, so the total ways are $n^k$.

Comment: I think "configuration" here means the balls are indistinguishable except for colors  so e.g. with 2 balls and 3 colors, it means the number of ways to write $2$ as an ordered sum of $3$ non-negative integers, i.e. to write $5$ as sum of $3$ positive integers, which is $C(4,2)$ by a standard stars-and-bars argument. Same reasoning in the general case. Look up "stars and bars" if you haven't seen the term before.

Comment: @saulspatz if there are three colored balls Red(R), Green(G), Blue(B) then
RR
RG
RB
GR
GG
GB
BR
BG
BB
here RG=GR , GB=BG, RB=BR so :
RR
RG
RB
GG
GB
BB
are the configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer from the wiki page

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

and the video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTCScjoPymA

Answer (score 0):

Configuration isn't a technical term, but you must be talking combinations and not permutations.  Otherwise the comments would be correct.  So we're talking in totals.  if there are 10 balls and red/white for colors, you could have 10 red, 9 red 1 white, 8 red 2 white ... 0 red 10 white.  That's 11 ways it could be. In your formula, it would be 2+10-1C10 or 11C10 = 11.  So the formula checks out in that example.

In general, You're selecting how many balls are each color.  In order to keep track of all the ways it could happen, we can organize it like this:  Suppose there is a bucket of each color of balls and a clown standing in front of the first bucket.  You can tell him two commands: "Ball" and "Next".  If you tell him "Ball" he will give you a ball from the bucket.  If you tell him "Next" he will move to the next bucket.  As long as you say "Ball" K times, you will end up with K balls.  As long as you say "Next" N-1 times, you will have had a chance at every color.  It's possible to get any arrangement of colors you want, so it's complete, and every different order of commands will give you a different count of each color so it's unique.

This turns it into an easier counting problem: How many different ways can we arrange K ball commands (B) and N-1 next commands (N)?  There will be K+N-1 total commands and we need to choose K of them to be B. So (K+N-1)C(K)